# How to use the word "proposition"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Does it make sense to write "Therefore, the proposition statement of this essay is flawed"

Comment: I think you mean  "preface" which is a "preliminary statement" to an essay/book etc.

Comment: Basically, I have a essay question which says discuss this statement ................... I want to say that the statement is wrong, but I don't want to write out the whole statement in my essay nor do I want to write .I have proved that the essay question is wrong.. Would using the word preface make more sense

Answer (score 1):

The word "proposition" itself refers to a statement that *proposes* some idea that - for e.g., in the case of an essay question - is intended to be further discussed or debated.

From Google:

> **prop·o·si·tion**
>   ˌpräpəˈziSH(ə)n/ *noun*
>
> 1.
>   a statement or assertion that expresses a judgment or opinion.
>   "the proposition that all men are created equal"
>   synonyms:   theory, hypothesis, thesis, argument, premise, principle, theorem, concept, idea, statement
>   "the analysis derives from one proposition"

Also, from Dictionary.com:

> 6.
>   *Rhetoric.* a statement of the subject of an argument or a discourse, or of the course of action or essential idea to be advocated.
>
> 7.
>   *Logic.* a statement in which something is affirmed or denied, so that it can therefore be significantly characterized as either true or false.

Thus, to refer to a "proposition statement" is **redundant**. It suffices to simply refer to the proposition of an essay as being flawed - i.e.,:

**"Therefore, the proposition of this essay is flawed."**

**Extra note:** if simply saying "proposition" doesn't sound right to you, another word you might appropriately use is "proposal", as in **"Therefore, the proposal of this essay is flawed."**

Comment: Nice answer, references and examples, Hixsor. What do you think about terms along the lines of "proposition/proposal *in question*"?

Comment: @hmmn: "proposition/proposal _in question_" is legitimate, but sort of implies that it's being challenged - that is, it presumes some question of which it's the focus. This is appropriate if, indeed, you're presenting a challenge. But be aware that "in question" can't be thrown around as equivalent to, for example, "aforementioned" or "presented", which signals reference to but not debate of the proposition.

Comment: Your idea of "presented" seems like the best answer of all, especially considering the poster's comment that the proposal is not the proposal of the essay. Care to add "presented" to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  It's in territory that's often misused, so you'll have to account for the writer's skill in deciding what was intended, but consider this:

> "Therefore, the proposition of this essay is flawed"

versus

> "Therefore, the proposition statement of this essay is flawed"

The two are clearly different statements.  One's addressing the proposition itself, the other the statement of that proposition -- proposition is no longer even a noun here.

---

The question is therefore whether the proposition you quoted is flawed, or merely the author's statement of it.